# Can we pass multiple eval field in one command argument in Repeater Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datarepeater, commandargument

can we pass multiple eval field in one command argument.

my code is here

`<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Details" SortExpression="source">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("source") %>' CommandName="Download" Text='<%#Eval("source") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>`

I want to be pass many Eval field in single command argument with command name
if possible please show any reference.

Comment: Share code in text format not as image, It will be more helpful. Webruster and Imad solution will work for you :)

Comment: @kkZone my solution wil solve your need , i am passing many eval field with comma seperated and using the `command name` i am able to slit them at code behind

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is what you are asking as you didnt provide any code snippet i'm assuming like this

`CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ScrapId")+","+ Eval("UserId")%>'`

In code behind you can use retrieve values like this

```
protected void GridViews_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Comment")
    {
        string[] commandArgs = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
        string scrapid = commandArgs[0];
        string uid = commandArgs[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

`<%# Eval("Param1").ToString() + Eval("Param2").ToString() %>`